# Rails: Circular dependency in connected STI classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I have two classes: `Category` and `Meter`. Like a `Category`, a `Meter` has a name and is used to categorise various `Bill`s. The difference between them is that a `Meter` has several more connections and can have another `Category` or `Meter` as its parent.

I've implemented this domain using single-table inheritance, but when I'm trying to run the console or the tests or the server I get the `'load_missing_constant': Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Meter` error (the full trace is [here.](http://pastebin.com/eLExmbrU))

Here are the classes in question:

meter.rb:

```
class Meter < Category
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: Category
  has_many :meter_values, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tariffs, dependent: :destroy
  validates :init_meter, presence: true
  validates :init_meter, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.0 }


  def current_tariff
    tariffs.first
  end
end
```

category.rb:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bills, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :children, class_name: Meter, inverse_of: :parent, foreign_key: :parent_id

  validates_associated :bills
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Category` and `Meter` both reference each other in their class definitions, so neither can load without the other being loaded first.  If you put the `class_name` in quotes you should be good:

```
has_many :children, class_name: 'Meter', ...
```

My spidey sense is a little tingly, though, with your domain model. You may want to revisit your database design and see if there's another table that should be holding some or all of what is in `Meter` rather than using STI.

Comment: Thank you. And I did, eventually. That's a story for another day though. :)